# Laravel Create OR update related model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following function to create a new related model;

```
                //Create the results entry
                $result = new Result([
                    'result' => $total,
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                ]);

                //attach it to the fixture - parse through looking for the user_id or opponent_id
                //to match the current user in the loop.
                $fixture = LeagueFixture::where('league_id', $league_id)
                            ->where('gameweek', $gameweek)
                            ->where(function($q) use ($user){
                                $q->where('user_id', $user->id)
                                    ->orWhere('opponent_id', $user->id);
                            })
                            ->first();

                $fixture->results()->save($result);
```

The ->save() at the end does most of the magic, attaching the correct fixture_id to the result table. The problem is that if the function is run again, it creates new entries for the same results.

There is a firstOrCreate() method, but i don't know how to use this when saving a related model.

Thanks

Comment: Does the result table has a result_id PK ? Two fixtures can have the same result instance?

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly like this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete.

```
//Create or find a existing one...
$result = Result::firstOrCreate([
     'result' => $total,
     'user_id' => $user->id,
]);
//grab fixture...
$fixture = LeagueFixture::where('league_id', $league_id)
                        ->where('gameweek', $gameweek)
                        ->where(function($q) use ($user){
                            $q->where('user_id', $user->id)
                                ->orWhere('opponent_id', $user->id);
                        })
                        ->first();
 //associate (set fixture_id in $result equals to $fixture's key)
 //any previous association will disappear. 
 $fixture->results()->associate($result);
 //save to write changes in the database.
 $result->save()
```

you can check here (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L559). Laravel will search in your database and return if it found it or create a new.

Comment: Please read the question thoroughly before preparing an answer. As i stated, i know about this function. But this will not work when saving a related model - as per the example i put in the question. As you can see from my question, this is a **related** model, so there are extra fields that are filled automatically when creating via my example. Using your method (which i already knew about) will require me to lookup the fixture_id first, and then run the firstOrCreate function

Comment: Sry. My fault, I was working with something. I fixed now I hope it's what you're looking for. you can place any Result's specific attributes per instance in firstOrCreate() to find the correct one and then reassociate it with other fixture.

Comment: Thanks. Surely in order for the firstOrCreate to work properly, it's only checking against the result and user_id? To give some more info; users will have multiple results (linked to separate fixtures). So, unless the result is **exactly** the same as the first time the function was run, it will assume its a new entry..?

Comment: yes, as you can see here(https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L559) laravel execute this query: static::where($attributes)->first(). It means $attributes must contain something that identify a specific result properly otherwise it will not find one and it will create a new one.

Comment: you are probably using composite keys. which most people don't recommend. you can create a auto_increment key and any important search field make them index. This way you can findOrFirst by id. If you have a high rate deleting rows, add a softDelete and from time to time delete some rows.